# how do i replace the first 100 characters of all lines in a file using awk

Tags: replace, awk, nawk

How do I replace the first 100 characters of all lines in  a file using awk?  There is no field delimiter in this file.  All fields are fixed width.  And given the variation in the data, I cannot use a search and replace.

Comment: Didn't work.  the -r flag is illegal with my version.

sed  's/.{46}/" "/' with855st

Answer (score 2):

How about `sed`? To replace the first 100 characters with say `A`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.{100}/A/' file
```

If you're happy with the results rewrite the file using `-i`:

```
$ sed -ri 's/.{100}/A/' file
```

Comment: Didn't work. the -r flag is illegal with my version. 
sed 's/.{46}/" "/' with855st

Comment: Try `sed 's/.\{100\}/replacement text/'`

Comment: Okay this works.  But I was hoping to replace the characters with an equal number of replacements--eg 100 blanks.  I would just have to be literal with the replacement text I guess

Comment: In the end I did these set of commands.  They worked for me.  Thanks.
* sed 's/.\{178\}//'  with855st > with855st2  
* nawk '{ sub(/^/, "      ...    "); print }' with855st2 > with855st3  
* cut -c46-47 with855st > with855st3a  
* nawk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] "\t" $0}' with855st3a with855st3 > with855st4  
* nawk '{ sub(/^/, "0000000000                                   "); print }' with855st4 > with855st5

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print "replacing text..." substr($0,100)}'
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work.  It basically deleted the whole line except for 2 blanks.
nawk '{print " " substr($11,46)}' with855st

Comment: I think that you need to investigate more your file format then. This is basic gawk/nawk syntax, as you can find [here](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/nawk.1.html).

Comment: @schwartzray, why do you use `$11` ? @Sigismundo used `$0`

Comment: I used #11 because I ASSUMED, that was the starting column.  I really wish to replace columns 11 thru 46 with blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use pure shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read each line into shell variable REPLY
while read -r ; do
   echo "REPLACE text ... ${REPLY:100}"
done <file
```

#### Explanation

- `REPLY` is shell variable, refer http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html. `Set to the line of input read by the read builtin command when no arguments are supplied`
- `${REPLY:100}` - get the string after 100 characters.

Comment: +1: Did not know `REPLY` variable. Though you are **not** reading in an array. You are reading entire line in default variable. no?

Comment: Added more explanations about REPLY